# How to figure out that the state from the LS(dehydrated) matches combinereducer's shape to apply in preloadedstate?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers, redux-toolkit

In Redux toolkit Preloadedstate (dehydration from localstorage) should be the shape of combine reducer if shape is incorrect or new reducers is being added on consecutive updates, app might crash, how to compare the combine reducers shape and shape of the dehyadrate state from local storage.

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { CONFIG } from '../config/config';
import * as reducers from './models';

const reHydrateStore = () => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem(CONFIG.REDUX_APP_STATE);
    if (data) {
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }
    return undefined;
};

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: combineReducers({ ...reducers }),
    devTools: CONFIG.ENV === 'development' ? true : false,
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware(),
    preloadedState: reHydrateStore(), // **** heads down here *** => may crash if store shape not matches combinre reducer's sstate
});

// persisting store
store.subscribe(
    lodash.debounce(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(CONFIG.REDUX_APP_STATE, JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
    }, 1000),
);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = (): ReturnType<typeof useDispatch> => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really redux-toolkit specific. You are looking for the documentation on [schema version migrations](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/migrations.md) for redux-persist.

Essentially, you as a developer have to track which versions of your state are compatible with each other. That version will be saved together with the state and you can introduce migration functions to go from one version to the next.